# How to read data from Container public ip?

Tags: java, ip, ibm-cloud

I have created a Java server application and bound to IBM container and assigned one public IP to it.

Clients sending data to container IP and port 9080 but I am unable to read this data from my application.

Also I can't see the data in message log of the application.

Can we see data from the container log file?

Is there any way to use IP's to listen data from client devices?

Comment: Is this just a standard java application or a JEE application running on Liberty/Tomcat?

Comment: It is a standard Java application running on liberty.